# IME pad won't appear without restart

Tags: windows-7

Sometimes when I click on the button on the language bar for the IME pad, it won't show up. Is there any other way to get it to show up again besides restarting the computer?

Answer (score 1):

try go to task manager and terminate "imepadsv.exe".